# Exclude Oracle website from search engines?

Tags: c#, oracle, security, search-engine, robots.txt

I'm a C# developer and last year i took over some projects at work, which are websites made completely in Oracle. I have 0 experience with oracle. 
Suddenly the websites are visible on Google, which they are not supposed to... 
Can anyone help me how to avoid that?

I know about "robots.txt" but i don't know where to put it in Oracle. We're having a hard time finding the root. 
Does Oracle have a special way to fix this? or does anyone know any alternate solutions?

It's all located on a subdomain, if that's any help.

Comment: What do you mean by "made in Oracle"?

Comment: Sorry for not making it more clear, but honestly, I don't know. 
It's made by a former employee. but it's made of views and procedures, which i can access with TOAD.
It's oracle sql and a little bit html mixed together in the procedures

Answer (score 1):

I suppose, there is some Oracle CMS in use, like WebCenter Content. Any CMS, not only any one by Oracle has inbuild metadata management. If even not, there should be any access to an engine, which generates HTML from database or XML content.

What i would do - i would search for something in the backend of the Oracle CMS, where you can manage metadata of each web document. After you got it, add to every web document's meta data the robots meta tag `<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">`. Thats it.

In case the content of web documents is saved in the database, find a table with the content of web documents - if their heads are saved in the database separately - find them. Then run an INSERT query into each row of this table, with the meta robots tag i wrote above.

I can imagine, after INSERT query you will be forced to re-render all web documents - do it to make new head content appear.

Another way to go could be to create  X-Robots-Tag on your webserver (if there is any Apache or Nginx between your Tomcat and the web) and put into X-Robots-Tag the "noindex, nofollow"-rule. Whether Tomcat (or the like) supports X-Robots-Tag or similar - i don't know.